# Javascript equivalent function for vbscript MsgBox()

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I need to convert following function to javascript,

`MsgBox("Are you a programmer?",0,"Please answer")`

I think I can use `confirm("Are you a programmer?")`

but I want to know how to add button order there ?

Comment: What do you mean with button order ?

Comment: If `confirm` or `prompt` won't do, you'll have to create your own. Using a combination of html/css/js.

Comment: if I put, 0 = vbOKOnly(OK button only). and other numbers have deferent meanings

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not have the custimizability that vbscript does with this function. And yes, it is confirm(). For example,

```
var choice=confirm("pick a button");
if(choice) alert("you picked ok");
else alert("you picked cancel")
```

You cannot control what the buttons say like in vbscript.